# HQL select vs delete. Why delete with cross join doesn't work?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql

Why this is working:

```
@Query("from Ban b where b.banned.uuid = :uuid")
```

but this cause SQL syntax error:

```
@Query("delete Ban b where b.banned.uuid = :uuid")
```

Error message is: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cross join user user1_ where uuid=x'53......'' at line 1`

Comment: Can you provide your domain classes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither HQL nor, usually—at least as far as I know—SQL, supports joins in `delete` statements. However, you can emulate it with a subquery, something like:

```
delete Ban b where b.bannedid = (select bb.id from Banned bb where bb.uuid = :uuid)
```